# How to get value of Route attribute in dotNet Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller that starts like this

```
[Route("api/v1/[controller]")]
public class ReportController : ControllerBase
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get "api/v1/report" in one of the methods.

"Request.Path" returns it, but if I've added a route to the method such as

```
[HttpGet("store/{id}")]
```

it returns that added on to it, and I'd like to reliably get just the base route, without having to do string manipulation.

Comment: The route on the controller is technically not a base route. the entire thing is put together to store it in the route table.

Comment: Noted, I understand that the base route would be protocol/domain etc. Just wasn't sure how to refer to the first part vs the second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.GetType().CustomAttributes
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.AttributeType == typeof(RouteAttribute))
            .ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString()
            .Replace("[controller]",(string)this.RouteData.Values["controller"]);
```

I was able to find this by digging around, though I wish there was a cleaner way to get this. This returns a string of "api/v1/report"